# How to implement titanium/phonegap app with Wordpress with article and feedback creation?

Tags: wordpress, cordova, titanium

I found that most sample codes are read-only in the app, without post creation and response functionality.

I would like to create a mobile app (with titanium or phonegap) with post creation and response functionalities.

Any idea on how to implement it? Or any sample code that shows this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you are enough skilled you can use Apppresser ( http://apppresser.com - https://wordpress.org/plugins/apppresser/).

It is a framework that allows you to build your app in wordpress and publish it through PhoneGap. It allows also to integrate and use many PhoneGap libraries.

I used it on couple of project and it is great, but again, you have to be quite skilled because it is a framework and not a visual builder.

They also have lots of video tutorial in documentation section that can make your life easier.

The framework is free but there are some useful paid add ons. For a blog app free framework has all you need.

Hope this helps!